# Filemaker to Mongodb collection to show data using datatables

Tags: php, mongodb, datatable, filemaker

I have a a table on filemaker that has about 1 million + rows and growing. It has about 30 columns.  I need to display this on to the datatables on my PHP page. My research online says FileMaker to PHP is super slow. So, i am trying to get the data to a mongodb collection and then send it to the datatables.

Just wanted to know if its a good architectural decision ?

If yes, is there a good way to get the data from FM to Mongodb ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are OK with not having "live access" to the data in FileMaker then I'd periodically export the entire dataset and import into MongoDB. Unfortunately, that would only give you Read-Only access to the data and is a very poor halfbaked solution.

If you wan to continue to keep FileMaker as your primary datastorage I'd work on making it work better with PHP then attempt to work around by introducing another piece into your infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

Displaying one million rows on a webpage is going to be slow, no matter what the backend is. Do you want to do batch fetching? Infinite scroll? You can fetch batches straight from FileMaker 500 at a time and it should perform all right.